# how to output two or more rows results under each other sql

Tags: php, sql, database

I am making a music player and I want the user to be able to add music of album to a playlist he made. 
[it looks like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHT0y.png)

The problem is when i am printing the value of the user playlists. It only shows one value in each div
[it makes a div to every playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDO7M.png) and 
[it shows one playlist name in div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3wi7.png)

I want the users playlists name to be in one div.

```
do {
                $userplaylists_list = array($music_rs['user_playlist_name']);
                $artistname = htmlentities ($music_rs['artist_name']);
                $musiclink = htmlentities ($music_rs['music_link']);
                $playlistimage = htmlentities ($music_rs['playlist_image']);
                $musicartist = htmlentities ($music_rs['music_artist']);
                $musicname = htmlentities ($music_rs['music_name']);
                $playlistdesc = htmlentities ($music_rs['playlist_desc']);
                $playlistfolder = htmlentities ($music_rs['playlist_folder_name']);
                $artistfolder = htmlentities ($music_rs['folder_name']);
                $musicid = htmlentities ($music_rs['music_id']);
                $playlistid = htmlentities ($music_rs['playlist_id']);
                **$userplaylists = htmlentities ($music_rs['user_playlist_name']);**


                echo '
                    <li song="media/artists/'.$artistfolder.'/playlists/'.$playlistfolder.'/music/'.$musiclink.'" m&aname="'.$musicname.' - '.$musicartist.'" cover="media/artists/'.$playlistimage.'" artist="'.$musicartist.'"><span style="margin-left:5px">'.$musicname.'</span><br>
                        <span style="margin-left:5px; font-size:10px;">'.$musicartist.'</span>
                        <a data-pop="'.$musicid.'" class="music-list-nav-button" onclick="event.stopPropagation();""><i style="position: relative; top: 10px;" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
                            <div data-popup="'.$musicid.'" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" class="music-list-div">
                                <span data-pop class="single-music-options" style="background-color: transparent;border-top: 10px solid #2b2b2b00;"></span>
                                <a add_to_playlist_data-pop="'.$musicid.'" class="add_to_playlist-button"><span class="single-music-options">Add to playlist</span></a>
                                <div add_to_playlist_data-popup="'.$musicid.'" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" class="add_to_playlist_div">
                                    <span add_to_playlist_data-pop class="single-music-options" style="background-color: transparent;border-top: 10px solid #2b2b2b00;">x</span>
                                    <span class="single-playlist-options">'.$userplaylists.'</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="single-music-options">Go to artist</span>
                                **<a href="index.php?page=play&playlistID='.$playlistid.'">
                                    <span class="single-music-options">Go to playlist</span>
                                </a>**
                            </div>
                    </li>
                     ';
                } while ($music_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($music_query));
```

Comment: can you also show the query?